# Turn on/off greedy-ness in clojure re-patterns

Tags: regex, clojure

How to turn on/off greedy-ness in clojure re-patterns?

```
(re-find #"(.+)-(.+)" "hello-world-you") => ["hello-world-you" "hello-world" "you"]
```

vs

```
(re-find #"(.+)-(.+)" "hello-world-you") => ["hello-world-you" "hello" "world-you"]
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `?` makes quantifiers, such as `+`, non-greedy.  By default, they are greedy.

- Greedy: `(.+)`
- Non-greedy: `(.+?)`

---

By the way, this is just the direct, simple, and to-the-point answer.  @fge's answer suggests the *better* way of doing it.  Check it out for future expressions.

Answer (score 13):

Don't use `.+`, use a complemented character class: this avoids having to care about greediness at all.

You should have used this as a regex: `([^-]+)-([^-]+)`.

Always make the effort to qualify your input as well as possible. Here you wanted to match everything which is not a dash, once or more, and capture it (`([^-]+)`), then a dash (`-`), then (again) everything which is not a dash, once or more, and capture it (`([^-]+)`).

Relying on quantifiers' (non-)greediness is a fundamental error if you know you can describe your input *without* relying on it. Not only it is a source of error (as you yourself demonstrate), it is also a hindrance for the regex engine to perform at its maximum efficiency.

Comment: True, lazy expressions are for lazy people.  But then again, if we weren't lazy, we'd be using character arrays and `for` loops, instead of using regular expressions.

Comment: That is not the question. This is just bad regex practice. I know 85+% of regex sites recommend it, but those 85+% sites are just _wrong_.